# Initial rest condition applied on $x(t)$ vs $h(t)$

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals, linear-systems, causality

Define the LTI system $\mathcal{H} : x\mapsto y$

Define the convolution for continuous-time system :
$$
(x*h)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)\;\text{d}\tau
$$
The initial rest condition states that :

> An LTI system with an input signal $x(t)$ is causal if and only if $x(t)=0$, $\forall t<0$

Now I have noticed that in some textbooks, the definition of convolution would have $h(\tau)$ instead of $x(\tau)$ and $x(t-\tau)$ instead of $h(t-\tau)$ (since $x*h=h*x$) but the initial rest condition now becomes :

> An LTI system with an impulse response $h(t)$ is causal if and only if $h(t)=0$, $\forall t<0$

My question is :

> Why does commutativity allow that for a LTI system to be causal then in one definition $x(t)=0$, $\forall t<0$ while in another definition $h(t)=0$, $\forall t<0$ knowing that $x$ and $h$ are two different terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be clear that a property of a system, such as causality, cannot be determined by looking at its input signals. For a linear time-invariant system, it is its impulse response $h(t)$ from which properties such as causality or stability can be determined.

Only the second definition in the question is correct: a causal LTI system has an impulse response $h(t)$ which equals zero for $t<0$. This implies that the system's output at time $t_0$ only depends on values of the input signal $x(t)$ for $t\le t_0$, and not on future values $x(t)$, $t>t_0$.

The output signal of a causal LTI system can be written as

$$y(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}h(\tau)x(t-\tau)d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^tx(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau$$

An initial-rest condition just means that if the input $x(t)$ is zero for $t<t_0$ then the output $y(t)$ must also be zero for $t<t_0$.

Comment: So if we say something like "For any $t_{0}$ and any input $x(t)$ such that $x(t)=0$ for $t<t_{0},$ the corresponding output $y(t)$ must also be zero for $t<t_{0}"$ is only true if we know that the system is LTI causal?

Comment: Alright, got it thank you!

Comment: @xXACEXx: I correct my previous comment: the condition given in your comment is valid for causal linear systems. There are non-linear systems that satisfy this requirement but are not causal, and there are causal non-linear systems that do not satisfy this condition.

Comment: So if we prove that $h(t)=0$ when $t<0$, then we would be proving causality for LTI systems so then the statement in my previous comment would be valid. right? Because I am confusing between the necessary condition and the sufficient condition for the causality of LTI systems and how they are related.

Comment: @xXACEXx: An impulse response $h(t)$ is only a valid description of LTI systems anyway, so in that case everything is clear. I meant the condition $x(t)=0$ for $t<t_0$ implying $y(t)=0$ for $t<t_0$, which doesn't mention an impulse response. That latter condition is only valid for linear systems (they could be time-varying though).

Comment: Ahh now I get it thank you once more!

Comment: Sorry to interrupt once more, I was wondering regarding the integral formula you wrote, are you integrating with respect to $\tau$ in both cases?

Comment: @xXACEXx: Yes, sure, as written.